# How to set multiple extraJavaOptions for spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark

I used spark-submit.sh like this:

```sh
CMD=(
    "$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit"
    --deploy-mode client
    --master ${SPARK_MASTER}
    --driver-memory 6G
    --executor-memory 16G
    --executor-cores 2
    --total-executor-cores 6
    --conf "spark.rpc.message.maxSize=256"
    --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80"
    --name dp_alexnet
    --class ${MAIN_CLASS}
    ${JAR_FILE}
    --dataset ${DATA_DIR}
    --classes 10
    --aggregate true
    --upBound 10
    --extraCompute true
    --isTaskRemove true
    --taskStrategy mean
    --taskFraction 0.5
    --excludeEpoch 10
    --excludeIteration 200000
    --maxEpoch 100
    --batchSize 336
    --pb 1.0
    --isNewoptimizer true
    --isAdamOrSGD true
    --tensorBoardPath ${TENSORBOARD_LOG_DIR}
    --logPath ${LOG_FILE}
)

${CMD[@]}
```

But I got Error:

```sh
Error: Unrecognized option: -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80"
```

How can I set multiple options on spark.executor.extraJavaOptions when I use the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is quotation problem when you are trying to put all elements in array and then executing it.
You can try with this way to see if it helps to achieve successful execution of command:

```
CMD=(
"$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit"
--deploy-mode client
--master ${SPARK_MASTER}
--driver-memory 6G
--executor-memory 16G
--executor-cores 2
--total-executor-cores 6
--conf "spark.rpc.message.maxSize=256"
--conf '"spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80"'
--name dp_alexnet
--class ${MAIN_CLASS}
${JAR_FILE}
--dataset ${DATA_DIR}
--classes 10
--aggregate true
--upBound 10
--extraCompute true
--isTaskRemove true
--taskStrategy mean
--taskFraction 0.5
--excludeEpoch 10
--excludeIteration 200000
--maxEpoch 100
--batchSize 336
--pb 1.0
--isNewoptimizer true
--isAdamOrSGD true
--tensorBoardPath ${TENSORBOARD_LOG_DIR}
--logPath ${LOG_FILE}
)
eval ${CMD[@]}
```

Comment: It's not work :( ,  and I tried `'--conf "xxx"'` , `--conf '"xxx"'` , `--conf '\"xxx\"'`, the problem is still not solved :(

Comment: Did you tried with eval as I mentioned after adding single quote?

Comment: Oh...My fault. I ignored the 'eval'. the script works well now. Thanks for your help :)